# Device Info JSON is empty on certain phones

Tags: android

I want to send info about users device for better debugging. Its working on 90% of devices, but on some of them its returning empty `JSON` for some reason.

I know only about single case when its happening and its on `Samsung A71` (Android 11). I dont understand how BuildConfig is null or empty or Build data are missing.

Code:

```
    val osNames = Build.VERSION_CODES::class.java.fields
    val osName = osNames[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].name
    val deviceInfo = jsonObjectOfNonNull(
        "language" to app.getLanguage(),
        "platform" to "Android",
        "versionName" to com.project.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME,
        "versionCode" to com.project.BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE,
        "systemName" to osName,
        "systemCodeName" to Build.VERSION.CODENAME,
        "systemVersion" to Build.VERSION.RELEASE,
        "systemSdkInt" to Build.VERSION.SDK_INT,
        "deviceModel" to Build.MODEL,
        "deviceBrand" to Build.BRAND,
        "deviceBootloader" to Build.BOOTLOADER,
        "deviceDisplay" to Build.DISPLAY,
        "deviceProduct" to Build.PRODUCT,
        "deviceDevice" to Build.DEVICE,
        "deviceHardware" to Build.HARDWARE,
        "deviceManufacturer" to Build.MANUFACTURER,
        "timeZone" to TimeZone.getDefault().id,
        "timeZoneSecondsFromGMT" to TimeZone.getDefault().rawOffset / 1000
    )

fun jsonObjectOfNonNull(vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>) = JSONObject().apply {
    for ((n, v) in params) {
        if (v != null) put(n, v)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you defining "empty JSON"? Do you mean `{}`? Do you mean a JSON object with your field names but empty values? Do you mean something else? Also, might there be a problem in your implementation of `jsonObjectOfNonNull()`? I don't see any sign of such a function being part of standard Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, {} is basically sent instead of this json. jsonObjectOfNonNull() is basically adding only those keys into the json, which value is not null. So if you have key "deviceModel" with value null, its not added to the json at all.

Comment: With `"platform" to "Android"`, neither of those values is `null`. So, if you are getting `{}`, something would appear to be wrong with that function.